# Servlet to Upload File

Tags: java, servlets

I have a Servlet to upload files.  The code in this link: http://codepad.org/EjqmmGQQ

When I run it in Netbeans, it's Ok, nothing happens. But when I upload it on host and run it, an error Exception happen. I've searched on Internet but I can not fix it. So please help me to fix the error. Thanks so much.

> Error Exception: catch1: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "java.io.tmpdir" "read")

My website: http://nptn.s43.eatj.com/TestUploadFile/

Comment: Sounds like the application doesn't have access to the temp directory.

Comment: @MadConan: The error happen because of this code: items = upload.parseRequest(request);
So, please teach me how to fix it? Thanks so much

Comment: check if user which is used to start the "application server" has read/write permission to the temp dir. Or you can change temp dir where you are sure that user has permission there like this on linux: java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/some_user/Temp

Comment: @Zemzela: I really don't know how to change temp dir or check if user has read/write permission to the temp dir. So, Could you show me more detail for my code? Thanks so much.

Comment: This is not in code, but on OS level. First tell me which OS you're using. Also check which user is used for starting the app. Then see if that user has permission for accessing temp folder.

Comment: contact your host, and ask them for help, to give write permissions to the web application

Answer (score 0):

parseRequest method throws FileUploadException - if there are problems reading/parsing the request or storing files.

It looks like, your application that is running on server not having permission to upload the file. Could you try changing the location in your code?

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you Ravi Bansal. I've tried changing the location but It's doesn't work. It's so hard for me to find the server supporting .jsp and servlet. So Could you give me some free host supporting jsp? Thanks so much :)